# Android hindi font not displaying

Tags: php, android

In my android app.. a result is taken from server and displayed in app.. where two languages are there for user to select.. English and Hindi.. The english part is working fine and displaying correctly. .but for hindi text ,... ony '???????' is displaying insted of fonts... But when I saved hindi fonts in server ..it is displaying as hindi fonts olnly ... I am using php code for connecting with the server..do we need to change it to utf8.. do we need to change any thing in php file.. I am giving my php code and sql code below.. please check and if there any error pls help..

php

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will get single product details
 * A product is identified by product id (pid)
 */ 
// array for JSON response



$response = array();




// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';



// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();




// check for post data
if (isset($_GET["pinnum"])) 

{
    $pinnum = $_GET['pinnum'];



    // get a product from products table
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM pin1h WHERE pinnum = $pinnum");

    if (!empty($result)) {
        // check for empty result
        if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

            $result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

            $product = array();
            $product["pid"] = $result["pid"];
            $product["pinnum"] = $result["pinnum"];           
            $product["pinnacle"] = $result["pinnacle"];    

            $product["created_at"] = $result["created_at"];
            $product["updated_at"] = $result["updated_at"];


            // success
            $response["success"] = 1;

            // user node
            $response["product"] = array();

            array_push($response["product"], $product);

            // echoing JSON response
            echo json_encode($response);
        } else {
            // no product found
            $response["success"] = 0;
            $response["message"] = "No product found";

            // echo no users JSON
            echo json_encode($response);
        }
    } else {
        // no product found
        $response["success"] = 0;
        $response["message"] = "No product found";

        // echo no users JSON
        echo json_encode($response);
    }
} else {
    // required field is missing
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

sql code

```
CREATE TABLE pin1h(
pid int(11) primary key auto_increment,
pinnum int(11),
pinnacle text,
created_at timestamp default now(),
updated_at timestamp
);
```

Comment: Check loading website with hindi fonts in emulator and check if it shows hindi font fine. Maybe fonts not available in device.

Comment: no... when i copy paste hindi font ..in text view.. it is displaying..when taking from server only it is not displaying

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just a tought but i think you should check the encoding on the server to see if what you send is alright, because i had the same problem one time and it turned out the server was sending the bad string.

```
<?php

/*
* Following code will get single product details
* A product is identified by product id (pid)
*/
// array for JSON response



$response = array();




// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';



// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");




// check for post data
if (isset($_GET["pinnum"]))

{
$pinnum = $_GET['pinnum'];



// get a product from products table
$result = mysql_query("SELECT *FROM pin1h WHERE pinnum = $pinnum");

if (!empty($result)) {
// check for empty result
if (mysql_num_rows($result) > 0) {

$result = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$product = array();
$product["pid"] =$result["pid"];
$product["pinnum"] = $result["pinnum"];
$product["pinnacle"] = $result["pinnacle"];

$product["created_at"] = $result["created_at"];
$product["updated_at"] = $result["updated_at"];


// success
$response["success"] = 1;

// user node
$response["product"] = array();

array_push($response["product"], $product);

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
} else {
// no product found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No product found";

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// no product found
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "No product found";

// echo no users JSON
echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}
?>
```

Comment: What I need to  do for that

Comment: Because your problem sounds like an encoding one. Try to encode the response to UTF-8. NOTE the encoding should happen before the json_response();

Comment: In the php part after you retrieve the values from the database, right before you send the response. The encoding should happen before the `echo json_encode($response);` part.

Comment: can you please type it.. because I am not getting clear

Comment: `$product = array();

 $product["pid"] = utf8_encode ($result["pid"]);
 $product["pinnum"] = utf8_encode ($result["pinnum"]);           
 $product["pinnacle"] = utf8_encode ($result["pinnacle"]);    

 $product["created_at"] = utf8_encode ($result["created_at"]);
 $product["updated_at"] = utf8_encode ($result["updated_at"]);`. The encoding should happen when you create the response.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/47930/discussion-between-user3182577-and-jocheved)